# How can I access base class elements using inheritance

Tags: python, inheritance

I am using inheritance to access base class elements. I have defined driver object in environment class and inherited in base class. In base class I am trying to access this object.

However I am getting an error Environment has no object driver. How do I access this element?

```
class Environment(object):
  def __init__(self):
        driver = "webdriver.Chrome(D:\BrowserDriver\ChromeDriver\chromedriver.exe)"
        print self.driver


class base(Environment):
  def __init__(self):
    drive = self.driver
  def test_Home_Page(self):

# Screenshots relative paths
        ss_path = "/Test_MercuryTours_HomePage/"

# Using the driver instances created in EnvironmentSetup
        drive = self.driver
        print drive
env=Environment()
print env.setUp()
b=base()
print b.drive
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Environment(object):
  def __init__(self):
     self.driver = "webdriver.Chrome(D:\BrowserDriver\ChromeDriver\chromedriver.exe)"
     print self.driver


class base(Environment):
  def __init__(self):
     Environment.__init__(self)
     self.drive = self.driver


b=base()
print b.drive
```

Comment: so just inheriting is not enough?

Answer (score 1):

Add self to the variable driver, in the base class.
`def __init__(self):
    self.driver = "webdriver.C..."`
ps: similarly, to access drive, you need to change it to self.drive .
In the base class, try this.
`def __init__(self):
    Environment.__init__(self)
    self.driver = "webdriver.C..."` .
Find out more about the Super keyword used for inheritance.

Comment: I did and the result is the same.I get an error saying driver(referring to the base class) is AttributeError: 'base' object has no attribute 'driver'

Comment: In the base class, try this.  
`def __init__(self):  
    Environment.__init__(self) . 
    self.driver = "webdriver.C..."
`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576169/understanding-python-super-with-init-methods . 
This would provide a better understanding of super keyword used in inheritance.